# What is the densest known exoplanet?

Tags: exoplanet

55 Cancri e is said to be 60 percent larger in diameter than Earth but have 8 times, the mass, making it twice as dense as Earth, and almost as dense as lead.

https://www.space.com/11544-densest-alien-planet-55cancrie.html

According to those figures it would have 8 times the mass of Earth in 4.096 times the volume, or 1.953125 times Earth's density.  Since the density of Earth is 5.514 grams per cubic centimeter, 55 Cancri e should have a density of 10.769531 grams per cubic centimeter.  Lead has a density at room temperature of about 11.34 grams per cubic centimeter.

According to Wikipedia:

> The mass of the exoplanet is about 8.63 Earth masses and its diameter is about twice that of the Earth,[2](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2299504-extremely-dense-planet-with-an-enormous-iron-core-has-an-8-hour-year/) thus classifying it as the first super-Earth discovered around a main sequence star, predating Gliese 876 d by a year.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/55_Cancri_e

With 8.396 Earth mass and twice the diameter of Earth 55 Cancri e would have 1.0495 times the density of Earth, or 5.7869 grams per cubic centimeter.

> The radial velocity method used to detect 55 Cancri e obtains the minimum mass of 7.8 times that of Earth,[2](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2299504-extremely-dense-planet-with-an-enormous-iron-core-has-an-8-hour-year/) or 48% of the mass of Neptune. The transit shows that its inclination is about 83.4 ± 1.7, so the real mass is close to the minimum. 55 Cancri e is also coplanar with b.

And the density is given as 6.66 grams per cubic centimeter, giving this as the source:

https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018A%26A...619A...1B/abstract

Planet GJ 367 b is also considered to be very dense.

> They found that the exoplanet has a radius about 72 per cent of Earth’s and a mass just over half our planet’s mass. With those measurements, they were able to predict its interior structure – it probably has an iron core that takes up about 86 per cent of its radius, similar to Mercury’s strangely huge iron core.

https://www.newscientist.com/article/2299504-extremely-dense-planet-with-an-enormous-iron-core-has-an-8-hour-year/

According to those rough figures, the planet would have at least 0.5 of Earth's mass in about 0.373248 of Earth's volume, and thus about 1.33959 of Earth's density - 7.3865 grams per cubic centimeter. Iron has a density of 7.874 grams per cubic centimeter.

According to NASA, GJ 367 b has a mass of 0.546 Earths and a radius of 0.718 Earth, which would give it 0.3701462 the volume of Earth and a density of 1.475 Earth or about 8.13366 grams per cubic centimeter.

https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/exoplanet-catalog/8049/gj-367-b/

This report says:

> GJ 367b has a radius of 0.718 ± 0.054 Earth-radii and a mass of 0.546 ± 0.078 Earth-masses, making it a sub-Earth planet. The corresponding bulk density is 8.106 ± 2.165 grams per cubic centimeter—close to that of iron.

https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aay3253

Wikipedia's list of exoplanet extremes lists the densest exoplanet as Kepler-131 c, with a highly uncertain density of 77.7 plus or minus 55 grams per cubic centimeter - between 22 and 132 grams per cubic centimeter.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_exoplanet_extremes#Planetary_characteristics

It gives the source as:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4195

On page 23 they discuss the two planets of Kepler-131:

> Kepler identified two transiting planets with orbital
> periods of 16.0 and 25.5 d and radii 2.4 and 0.8 R⊕

> The RV measurements for Kepler-131 span 741 days
> (Figure 30, top) and are listed, along with their
> log R′
> HK activity values in Table 18. The results consist
> of an RV detection of the 16 d planet giving a mass of
> 16.1 ± 3.5 M⊕, and a density of 6.0 ± 2.0 g cm−3
> . We
> find a similar mass and density whether we fit this planet
> by itself or with the second planet simultaneously. The
> second planet shows up in the RVs only marginally. A
> self-consistent fit of RVs and photometry yields a peak
> of the posterior mass distribution at M = 8.25 ± 5.9
> M⊕ and density of 78 ± 55 g cm<sup>−3</sup>
> . The density is unphysically large, and hence the mass is too large, indeed
> a detection at less than 2σ. We find an upper limit to
> the mass of Kepler-131c from the 95th percentile of the
> posterior mass distribution, yielding M < 20.0 M⊕ . Certainly the mass of Kepler-131c remains highly uncertain.
> Table 2 lists all of the best-fit planet parameters.

Kepler-131 c should have a radius of about 0.8 Earth & thus a volume of about 0.512 Earth and so with a mass of 8.25 plus or minus 5.9 times the mass of Earth it should have a density between about 4.5898 and 27.6368 times Earth's density, 25.308 to 152.388 grams per cubic centimeter.

And since the calculated density of Kepler-131 c was so unbelievably large, I have to wonder if anyone has tried to measure its radius and/or mass again since 2014.

So what is the densest known exoplanet now in 2022, and are there any known  exoplanets which might possibly have higher densities?

Answer (score 1):

Kepler-131c density is unphysically high.

A better candidate for most dense is kelt-1-b at  23.7±4.0 gcm<sup>−3</sup>
https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04533